# How to respond to tkinter events?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm doing some work with GUI in python. I'm using the Tkinter library.

I need a button, which will open a .txt file and do this bit of processing:

```
frequencies = collections.defaultdict(int)    # <-----------------------
with open("test.txt") as f_in:                  
    for line in f_in:
        for char in line:
            frequencies[char] += 1
total = float(sum(frequencies.values()))      #<-------------------------
```

I started with:

```
from Tkinter import *               
import tkFileDialog,Tkconstants,collections

root = Tk()
root.title("TEST")
root.geometry("800x600")

button_opt = {'fill': Tkconstants.BOTH, 'padx': 66, 'pady': 5}
fileName = ''
def openFile():
    fileName = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root,title="Open .txt file", filetypes=[("txt file",".txt"),("All files",".*")])
Button(root, text = 'Open .txt file', fg = 'black', command= openFile).pack(**button_opt)



frequencies = collections.defaultdict(int)    # <-----------------------
with open("test.txt") as f_in:                  
    for line in f_in:
        for char in line:
            frequencies[char] += 1
total = float(sum(frequencies.values()))      #<-------------------------



root.mainloop()
```

Now I don't know how to assemble my code so it runs when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was `tkFileDialog.askopenfile()` returns an open `file` rather than a file name. This following seemed to be more-or-less working for me:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog, Tkconstants,collections

root = Tk()
root.title("TEST")
root.geometry("800x600")

def openFile():
    f_in = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(
                            parent=root,
                            title="Open .txt file",
                            filetypes=[("txt file",".txt"),("All files",".*")])

    frequencies = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for line in f_in:
        for char in line:
            frequencies[char] += 1
    f_in.close()
    total = float(sum(frequencies.values()))
    print 'total:', total

button_opt = {'fill': Tkconstants.BOTH, 'padx': 66, 'pady': 5}
fileName = ''
Button(root, text = 'Open .txt file',
       fg = 'black',
       command= openFile).pack(**button_opt)

root.mainloop()
```

For quickly creating simple GUI programs I highly recommend [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net), a fairly powerful yet simple `Tk`--based Python module for doing such things.

Comment: Beat out by 3 minutes... +1 Good answer, a lot less complicated then mine too.

Answer (score 1):

Try something laid out a bit like this:

```
class my_app():
    def __init__():
        self.hi_there = Tkinter.Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)

    def say_hi():
        # do stuff
```

You also may want to read:

[This tutorial on Tkinter,](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/events-and-bindings.htm#AEN676)

[And this one.](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/events-and-bindings.htm)

**EDIT:**  The OP wanted an example with his code (I think) so here it is:

```
from Tkinter import *               
import tkFileDialog,Tkconstants,collections

class my_app:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button_opt = {'fill': Tkconstants.BOTH, 'padx': 66, 'pady': 5}
        self.button = Button(frame, text = 'Open .txt file', fg = 'black', command= self.openFile).pack(**button_opt)

        self.calc_button = Button(frame, text = 'Calculate', fg = 'black', command= self.calculate).pack()

        self.fileName = ''

    def openFile():
        fileName = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root,title="Open .txt file", filetypes=[("txt file",".txt"),("All files",".*")])

    def calculate():
        ############################################### *See note
        frequencies = collections.defaultdict(int)    # <-----------------------
        with open("test.txt") as f_in:                  
            for line in f_in:
               for char in line:
                   frequencies[char] += 1
        total = float(sum(frequencies.values()))      #<-------------------------
        ################################################

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.title("TEST")
root.geometry("800x600")

root.mainloop()
```

*Note: Nowhere in your code did I see where collections came from so I wasn't quite sure what to do with that block.  In this example I have set it to run on the

Comment: Thanks for help, but i still don't get it work. Can you please copy code of your example?

Answer (score 0):

In your `openFile()` function, just after you ask the user for a file name, put your code!

Comment: Well this is not working, I tried this, but when I run it, first open window dialog, to open text.file. I want button, then click it and open .txt file, then do this what is in "code"